# Multivalue data into columns into rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split, position, sql-server-2016

I am trying to split data from various fields and then I have to take it from columns into rows.
Currently all the charges for 1 client is stored in one field. So is all the descriptions of the charges stored in another field.
I have data that currently looks like this in SQL

```
ID              ChargeType    ChargeAmount
1000:1597       F^F^F         1000^500^250
01000:6597      F^F^F^F^F     500^250^50^2000^1000
00010:0001      F             70
```

I have used mainly XML to split the charges and the charge types into columns.
I have successfully split charges and the amount and able to join but that gave me the incorrect count of charges.

```
Create table Charges(
        IDx int,
        ID varchar(55),
        ChargeAmount varchar(55),
        ChargeType varchar(55)
        )


DECLARE @chargetype TABLE(IDx int Identity, ID varchar(max), data1 varchar(max))

INSERT INTO @chargetype SELECT ID, ChargesType from TrnDeal
SELECT 
F1.IDx,
F1.ID,
O.ChargesType
into #tempsplitchargetype
FROM
 (
 SELECT *,
 cast('<Y>'+replace(F.data1,'^','</Y><Y>')+'</Y>' as XML) as xmlfilter
  from @chargetype F
  )F1
  CROSS Apply
  ( 
  SELECT fdata1.D.value('.','varchar(50)') as ChargesType
  FROM F1.xmlfilter.nodes('Y') as fdata1(D)) O

 DECLARE @chargeamount TABLE(IDx int IDENTITY, ID varchar(max), data1                     
varchar(max))
INSERT INTO @chargeamount SELECT ID, ChargesAmount from TrnDeal
 SELECT 
S1.IDx,
S1.ID,
M.ChargeAmount
into #tempsplitchargeamount
FROM
 (
 SELECT *,
 cast('<X>'+replace(S.data1,'^','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as xmlfilter
 from @chargeamount S
 )S1
 CROSS APPLY
 ( 
 SELECT Fdata.D.value('.','varchar(50)') as ChargeAmount 
 FROM S1.xmlfilter.nodes('X') as fdata(D)) M

-- Insert into dbo.Charges
 Select CA.IDx, CA.ID, CA.ChargeAmount, b.ChargesType
    from #tempsplitchargeamount CA
    outer apply (Select IDx, ChargesType from #tempsplitchargetype) b
    where CA.IDx = b.IDx
```

I am expecting the data to look as follow for 1 client as example.

```
ID              ChargeType    ChargeAmount
1000:1597       F             1000
1000:1597       F             500
1000:1597       F             250
01000:6597      F             500
01000:6597      F             250
01000:6597      F             50
01000:6597      F             2000
01000:6597      F             1000
```

Comment: Please tag with the appropriate RDBMS. I assume, this is SQL-Server? And please tag with the version, as there are some nice features coming with v2012 or v2016...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tagged this with `[SSMS-2017]`. This is not enough to be sure about your RDBMS, but I assume, that you are using SQL-Server 2016 or a higher version...

First of all I'd like to state, that your most important question is: Why do you store this in CSV-format? This is breaking `1.NF`... If you can change the table's layout, you should use a related side-table.

But - if you have to stick with it - you can use a trick with `JSON`:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID VARCHAR(100),ChargeType VARCHAR(100),ChargeAmount VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup(ID,ChargeType,ChargeAmount) VALUES
 ('1000:1597','F^F^F','1000^500^250')
,('01000:6597','F^F^F^F^F','500^250^50^2000^1000')
,('00010:0001','F','70');

SELECT m.ID
      ,B.[key] AS Position
      ,B.[value] AS ChargeType
      ,JSON_VALUE(A.AmountAsJson,CONCAT('$[',B.[key],']') COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2) AS ChargeAmount
FROM @mockup m
CROSS APPLY (SELECT JSON_QUERY('["' + REPLACE(m.ChargeAmount,'^','","') + '"]')) A(AmountAsJson)
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(m.ChargeType,'^','","') + '"]') B 
ORDER BY m.ID 
        ,Position;
```

The result:

```
+------------+----------+------------+--------------+
| ID         | Position | ChargeType | ChargeAmount |
+------------+----------+------------+--------------+
| 00010:0001 | 0        | F          | 70           |
+------------+----------+------------+--------------+
| 01000:6597 | 0        | F          | 500          |
+------------+----------+------------+--------------+
| 01000:6597 | 1        | F          | 250          |
+------------+----------+------------+--------------+
| 01000:6597 | 2        | F          | 50           |
+------------+----------+------------+--------------+
| 01000:6597 | 3        | F          | 2000         |
+------------+----------+------------+--------------+
| 01000:6597 | 4        | F          | 1000         |
+------------+----------+------------+--------------+
| 1000:1597  | 0        | F          | 1000         |
+------------+----------+------------+--------------+
| 1000:1597  | 1        | F          | 500          |
+------------+----------+------------+--------------+
| 1000:1597  | 2        | F          | 250          |
+------------+----------+------------+--------------+
```

The idea in short:

String splitting is a pain within SQL-Server's TSQL. There were various workarounds using loops, recursive CTEs or XML (as you do above).
With v2016 developers were very happy about the new function `STRING_SPLIT()`, but MS forgot to provide the fragment's position. This makes `STRING_SPLIT()` a pretty useless function...

But - together with `STRING_SPLIT` - JSON support was introduced. Reading a simple JSON-array with `OPENJSON` will provide the fragment's position in the column `[key]` (attention: zero-based!).

The code above will first create a *mockup-table* and fill it with your sample data.
The first`CROSS APPLY` will transform the `ChargeAmount` into a JSON-array without doing anything with it.
The second`CROSS APPLY` will transform the `ChargeType` into a JSON-array and return one row per fragment.
The select then uses `JSON_VALUE` to pick the corresponding value out of `AmountAsJson` by using the `[key]` (the position) as JSON path.

Hope this was clear...

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you and your explanation was very clear. Will have to up skill myself a bit for JSON.